# What does fsck mean with “Filesystem has n clusters but only space for n-m FAT entries. (m>0)”?

Tags: filesystems, filesystem-corruption, hard-drive-failure, fsck

I started a long time copy action onto my external HD. I went away, and somehow the energy saving mechanism must have realized that the user was idle and suspended the machine. (BTW, what exactly is the definition of "user being idle"? I did not type anything, did some cooking, but my process was surely not idle.) Now the HD can be mounted only read-only. fsck says:

```
$ sudo fsck.vfat -V /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for heino: 
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
Filesystem has 30516268 clusters but only space for 30516222 FAT entries.
```

and stops working. What does that mean? What can I do now?

Comment: Too many clusters (basic units of logical storage on a hard disk) and not enough space to give each one an entry in the file allocation table (FAT). The FAT is a map of the clusters and it looks like it wouldn't be able to access all of them in this case. I hope that sheds light on your problem, but I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will actually solve your problem, but this article has some nice hints, particularly note the -a -r options you have to apply.

[Unable to resolve data corruption warning with fcs](https://serverfault.com/questions/571458/unable-to-resolve-data-corruption-warning-with-fcsk)

> This is stupid. I find myself answering my own question again. It
>   says,
>
> ```
> Leaving filesystem unchanged.
> ```
>
> suggesting that nothing is changed. This actually mean that typing 1
>   followed by pressing enter inside the fsck prompt did not work.
>   Anyway, the following does work:
>
> `$ fsck.vfat -v -a -w /dev/sda1`
>
> The above command automatically write changes to disk. It would be
>   great if anyone can tell me whether this is a bug in fsck or it is due
>   to something else.